# Why didn't anyone use the reparo spell on Harry's broom?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry fell from the sky mid-way a Quidditch match due to a dementor attack, his broom got destroyed after falling into/on the Whomping Willow.

Why didn't anyone use the *Reparo* spell to repair it? Is it because it's so badly destroyed that even that spell couldn't fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one thing, it doesn't appear as if all parts of it were recovered:

> Slowly, she reached down for a bag at her feet, turned it upside down, and tipped a dozen bits of splintered wood and twig onto the bed, the only remains of Harry's faithful, finally beaten broomstick.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 9</sub>

The way this is presented - that's it's **all that remains** - implies that it isn't all the pieces of it. It was smashed to *bits*, which means that it would be almost impossible to recover all parts of it. It wouldn't do much good to only put half the broomstick back together!

Additionally, magic has limits. The broomstick was really destroyed. It's possible that magic couldn't fix it.

Comment: (+1) I always assumed brooms worked just like wands; once broken, they become near useless

Comment: (You name thief, you!) It's also possible that the magic that makes it fly is broken when it's smashed, yes.

Comment: @Olórin - When coupled with [Rowling's tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/707226426274086912) comparing them, you may have a good answer.

Comment: magic can't fix everything...

Answer (score 4):

Why didn't Reparo work on Harry's wand?? Maybe the physical structure of the broom could have been restored with Reparo, but I assume it would have lost most of its magical power. Hermione tried to repair Harry's broken wand in the Deathly Hallows but it did not work:

> ‘Where’s my wand, Hermione?’ She was biting her lip, and tears swam in her eyes. ‘Harry ...’ ‘Where’s my wand?’ She reached down beside the bed and held it out to him. The holly and phoenix wand was nearly severed in two. One fragile strand of phoenix feather kept both pieces hanging together. The wood had splintered apart completely. Harry took it into his hands as though it was a living thing that had suffered a terrible injury. He could not think properly: everything was a blur of panic and fear. Then he held out the wand to Hermione.
>   ‘Mend it. Please.’
>   ‘Harry, I don’t think, when it’s broken like this –’
>   ‘Please, Hermione, try!’
>   ‘R – Reparo.’ The dangling half of the wand resealed itself. Harry held it up. ‘Lumos!’
>   The wand sparked feebly, then went out. Harry pointed it at Hermione.
>   ‘Expelliarmus!’
>   Hermione’s wand gave a little jerk, but did not leave her hand. The feeble attempt at magic was too much for Harry’s wand, which split into two again

If only SOMEONE had the Elder wand......:|

Comment: Makes sense. Even Ron's wand example can be quoted too :)